# fopen doesn’t create file in the current directory

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, fopen

I have created a console application in VS2010 and I want to create a file in the current directory where the exe runs. I used the following code

`fp = fopen("Pkts.csv", "w+");`

But file is not getting created in the current directory and the file pointer is not NULL. But when I specifies the path as

`fp = fopen("C:\\Windows\\Pkts.csv", "w+");`

the file gets created in the path specified. How to create the file in the current directory?

Comment: Are you running the `.exe` from within Visual Studio (using the "Start Debugging" or "Start Without Debugging" option)? Try running the thing from the command line (or just double-clicking it directly).

Comment: What do you mean "where the exe runs"?

Comment: I copied the exe to another machine and run it from the command line

Comment: @indira- where is it getting created or its not getting created at all?

Comment: @CarlNorum: When running the `.exe` from Visual Studio's "Start (Without) Debugging" function the current directory is not set to where the `.exe` is located, but in the output directory you set in the project settings. The file might be created but located somewhere else.

Comment: @indira: Check the value of `fopen()`. If it's `NULL`, check the value for `errno`.

Comment: You can use [`_getcwd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to check what the current directory actually is.

Answer (score 1):

What's `fp`'s value when you try to fopen it in the current directory? If it's null, something went wrong. It could be a permission issue. If not, then you should make sure the file isn't created somewhere else by writing to that file and then trying to open it again (maybe you're looking at the wrong directory and assuming that is the working directory).

Answer (score 0):

when you running the .exe from within Visual Studio. the file will be created in the root of your project directory.
try running  .exe whithout Visual Studio

Comment: [The OP has already tried running it directly from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919458/fopen-doesnt-create-file-in-the-current-directory#comment12660129_9919458).

Comment: the file gets created if the path is correctly specified. If I like to get the file created in the same directory where the exe runs, its not created